# Search Api display search term in form

Tags: 8, search

How do I display the search term after I have run the search.

Here is my form:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-search-api-fulltext" id="edit-search-api-fulltext"  placeholder="Keyword" name="search_api_fulltext" value="{{ content.search_api_fulltext }}" class="regular-input" type="text">
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-search" id="edit-submit-search" placeholder="Search" value="Search" class="btn secondary-btn js-form-submit form-submit" type="submit">
```

The value is not displaying anything, but I can't find an answer to what I should place here.
Before installing Search Api I used {{ content.search_query }} and that displayed the search term after the search was performed using the out-of-the-box Drupal search.

Comment: "Search" and "Search API" are different modules. You'd have to check and see what template variables are available to use.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I explained what worked for me using search as an example of what i'm trying to do and said that I can't get it to work with Search API. I can't find anything that tells me what template variables I can use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Drupal 9, and I had to create a variable in the theme and use it in my custom form template

In mytheme.theme

```
function hook_theme_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['search_term'] = \Drupal::request()->query->get('search');
}
```

In my customtemplate.twig

```
<input value="{{ search_term }}" >
```